# Display an XML field nicely in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: xml, activeadmin

One of my table fields contains XML data saved as a string. I want to display it in ActiveAdmin in a readable way. I found a way to do do this, but it's unbelievably hackish.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register SyncLog do
  show do
    attributes_table do
      row :request do |log|
        if log.request
          xml_string = Nokogiri::XML(log.request, &:noblanks).to_xml
          "<pre>#{xml_string.gsub(/</, '&lt;').gsub(/>/, '&gt;')}</pre>".html_safe
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

A string in the DB might be:

```
"<foo>\n<bar />\n</foo>"
```

And I want to display it as:

```
<foo>
   <bar/>
</foo>
```

How could I achieve this in a good way?

Answer (score 1):

This is decorator usage candidate.
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/11-decorators.md

Something like this may work

```
class SyncLogDecorator
   def request
    xml_string  = Nokogiri::XML(model.request, &:noblanks).to_xml
    "<pre>#{xml_string.gsub(/</, '&lt;').gsub(/>/, '&gt;')}</pre>".html_safe
   end
end


ActiveAdmin.register SyncLog do
  decorate_with SyncLogDecorator
end
```